# Stats is not maths?

Tags: statistics, soft-question, meta-math

How mainstream is the claim that stats is not maths? And if it's right, how many people don't agree?

Given that it's all numbers, taught by maths departments and you get maths credits for it, I wonder whether the claim is just half-jokingly meant, like saying it's a minor part of maths, or just applied maths.

Comment: "Taught by maths departments": Not always!  And many things that rely on numbers are not mathematics, e.g. numerology.

Comment: Stats is a very sexy field right now because machine learning is such a hot area. And machine learning is of high interest in applied math.

Comment: ‘Probability is mathematics; statistics is theology.’ Unfortunately, I don’t remember where I found that.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thomas Bayes was  mathematician and theologian. Maybe that started the confusion.

Answer (score 6):

Statistics can be thought of as an application of mathematics towards the rather specific goal of examining numerical data.

In order to understand statistics, you should probably know some mathematics. In a similar manner, in order to understand engineering, you should probably know some mathematics.

But just like in engineering (or any other applied field), there are domain-specific definitions, terms, and conventions that arise extrinsically from mathematics. For example, the $p$-value is a concept that arose to make sense of data. It can be mathematically studied, but it did not necessarily arise as a natural extension of some prior mathematical definition.

Answer (score 0):

At my university, the departments are separate. While they have a bit of interaction (i.e. we share a restroom on the second floor), there is very little contact between the two departments. This is true from the earliest freshman classes, clear through to professorial research. The two departments really do not interact. So while the subject matter may be similar ("numbers"), for all intents and purposes, the two fields might as well be totally separate.

One other thing I note is that to get a math degree at my institution, one needs to take a single stats course. In fact, only one stats course can even be counted towards a degree in math. That is the most they will count. But, the stats department requires multiple math courses to earn a degree (BS) in stats.

My personal view on the matter is that stats is a branch of applied math, much like earning a degree in Korean is a branch of linguistics; but, much of the lingual theory of the latter is avoided in earning the former.

Comment: Restroom interaction is fundamental.

Answer (score -1):

In my university thee are three departaments: Stats, Mathematics, and Mathematical Engineering. The reserch topics of those departaments are different, the hyperspecilization is a general paradigm in the world.

Answer (score -3):

How you want to define what is counted as mathematics is up to you.

For me, mathematics is reasoning, and most of the stats classes I've seen have had no reason whatsoever.  It was all memorization and "this is true by definition" when professors didn't know what the background material was.

Statistics can be a great mathematical study, for someone who starts with a strong background in probability and counting.

---

Aside...

One problem that faces prob/stat is the lack of a good calculus.  It's not accidental that most computer algebras don't have probability support, and when they do it's nearly unusable.  Consider the following word problem:

"You roll a 6 sided dice.  What is the probability that it comes up one?"
Answer: 1/6

"Added information: the evens are twice as heavy (likely to land) as the odds."
Answer: 1/9

An intuitive approach to a calculus of probability breaks the rule:
$$\underline{A \vdash B} \\
A \land X \vdash B$$

Furthermore, in complex problems random variables do a poor job of capturing complex propositional dependencies and independencies.

Simple examples can be explained away with intuition, but the point of a calculus is to avoid the need for intution (as far as verification goes anyway).  I'm sure my opinion is in the minority, but I still think that there is a lot of good progress that can be make in foundations of prob/stat.

Comment: "I still think that there is a lot of good progress that can be make in foundations of prob/stat." Do you think there is a possibility that such foundations do exist but you do not know those foundations?

Comment: The concrete example does not prove what is said. Actually the two problems are "Roll a 6 sided dice and assume the results are equiprobable. What is the probability that 1 comes up? Answer: 1/6" and "Roll a 6 sided dice and assume the evens are equiprobable, the odds are equiprobable, and the evens are twice as likely as the odds. What is the probability that 1 comes up? Answer: 1/9." To sum up:$$\underline{A \land X\vdash B} \\
A \land Y \vdash C$$

Comment: @Lord Soth http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/592869/we-are-dealt-a-five-card-poker-hand-the-probability-that-this-hand-contains-exa Several answers, all of them rely on intuition.  It will be the same with nearly any other probability/counting problem you find.  You and I can read these answers and see that they are correct with our intuition, which is fine, but we should also be able to show the answer formally.  A couple hundred years ago, even simple ratio problems couldn't be solved without intuition.  Imagine if today we still solved ratios like we solve counting problems.  Ugh.